# Monit ignore pipes for some reason

Tags: monit

I have Monit script to monitor my tvheadend service.
To start the program I would like to use start command

```
start program = "/etc/init.d/tvheadend start 
    && /usr/bin/python /root/antik_epg/antik_xmltv.py
    | /usr/bin/socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/etc/tvheadend/epggrab/xmltv.sock"
```

But for some reason the Monit ignores command after pipe.
It just starts `tvheadend` and only runs `/usr/bin/python /root/antik_epg/antik_xmltv.py`.

It does not run `/usr/bin/socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/etc/tvheadend/epggrab/xmltv.sock`

How to run all commands?
I have tried to run custom scripts:

```
start program = "/bin/ash -c '/root/tvheadend_start.sh'"
```

But the result was same.

The command runs perfectly directly from bash.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.
Instead of unnamed pipe I have used named pipe.

```
start program = "/bin/ash -c /root/tvheadend_start.sh"
```

In the /root/tvheadend_start.sh script:

```
#!/bin/sh    
/etc/init.d/tvheadend start
/usr/bin/python /root/antik_epg/antik_xmltv.py > /root/pipe &
/usr/bin/socat - UNIX-CONNECT:/etc/tvheadend/epggrab/xmltv.sock < /root/pipe &
```